# Reaching the continuum through countably infinite steps

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, infinity

Let the following set,
$$S_n = \left \{0, \frac 1 n, \frac 2 n, \dots, \frac {n-1}{n}\right\}, \quad n \in \mathbb N_+.$$

I read that if

$$n\to \infty \implies S_n \to [0,1]. \tag{1}$$

Namely, that as we "let $n$ go to infinity", the set $S_n$ becomes the interval $[0,1]$ of real numbers.

The only intuition I can think of is that the maximum element of $S_n$ is bounded so we are squeezing more and more numbers in a finite interval... any hint on how I could go about proving (or disproving) assertion $(1)$ formally?

Comment: What does it even mean that $S_n\to[0,1]$?

Comment: @AsafKaragila That as we let $n$ "go to infinity" the set $S_n$ becomes the interval $[0,1]$ of real numbers. How should I have written it?

Comment: It really depends on what you mean by $S_n \to [0, 1]$. There is a notion of convergence of sets but with the obvious notion of convergence (which basically amounts to taking the union) $S_n$ converges to $[0, 1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$. There is also a notion of convergence of *compact* subsets, namely Hausdorff convergence, which this might fit: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance

Comment: What do you mean by a limit of sequence of sets is equal to $[0,1]$ ?

Comment: But in what sense does it "become the interval"? It's a finite set of rational numbers. So you're either going to end up with just the rationals, or the limit process you're considering is more than the union, in which case you need to be extremely explicit about it.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks for phrasing the things that have been bothering me since I read this assertion.

Comment: Where did you even read that ridiculous statement?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Somewhere on the internet. $S_n$ is the support of a discrete Uniform random variable, and the assertion was that as $n \to \infty$ its distribution function converges to the distribution function of a continuous Uniform r.v. with support $[0,1]$.

Comment: There are senses in which statements like this are meaningful and true. For example, the set $\mathcal{K}$ of nonempty compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ has a natural metric - the Hausdorff metric - and with respect to this metric we do indeed have $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}S_n=[0,1]$. But this is a very specific technical fact, and one shouldn't simply assert "The $S_n$s tend to $[0,1]$" without a *lot* of context/caveats.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos *That* assertion is true.

Comment: It might be useful to observe that we now have two possible definitions of "convergence" that can make the assertion true. One is (pointwise) convergence of uniform cumulative probability distribution functions. The other is convergence in the Hausdorff metric. And these two definitions are not equivalent